# Why does Eclipse open my java files as a tab in the package explorer view?

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I want to open a file in the package explorer, it will be opened as a new tab in the same view as the package explorer. Last time I started Eclipse, the were all opened in a seperate editor view.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: ok. screenshot added

Comment: @GoGonania why do you keep removing the screen shot from the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try resetting your perspective.

In the upper right hand corner you can see your currently selected "Perspective" (you can also set it through Window-->Open Perspective-->Other). It will probably be "Java" for you. You can right-click on the perspective and choose "Reset". This will reset the perspective to it's default settings.

There is also Window>Reset Perspective as another way to reset.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and had to shift the newly opened tab manually.

Doing Window-> Perspective->Reset perspective brought the views to their default positions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont need it anymore :)
I haven't used Java or Eclipse for years.

Comment: Thank you, this was an annoying pickle I got myself into.

Answer (score 1):

open  Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective
It worked fine for me.
Then you can just minimize all the other open tabs you don't need like Task List...